# How to get content from a TinyMCE instance within an iframe

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I have an instance of TinyMCE (v5) which is inside an iframe itself. However, I want its content to be included when I submit a form in the parent page. Since its content is not added automatically to the POST data, I'm trying to intercept the form submit, copy the content of the TinyMCE instance to a hidden field out of the iframe, and proceed with the submission.

However, I'm having trouble getting to the TinyMCE instance within the iframe.

I managed to access the contents of the iframe this way:
`$('#iframe').contents().find('[name="input"]')`

And I know that to get a TinyMCE instance's content we should use `getContent()`.
I can't, however, get the TinyMCE instance from outside the iframe.

I also tried initialising TinyMCE from outside the iframe (i.e., from the parent page) by using the `target` option instead of `selector`, but in that case TinyMCE wouldn't even initialise properly.

Is there any way to get the iframe's TinyMCE instance? It's important for me to keep it inside the iframe because I want the editor's CSS to be independent from the main page's.

Comment: `tinymce` should be a global property of the global `window` object of the iframe. To access it, you can simply do `$("#iframe")[0].contentWindow.tinymce`. Then, to get the editor's content _(not tested since I don't have acces to v5, but works in v4)_: `$("#iframe")[0].contentWindow.tinymce.editors["input-id"].getContent()` _(replace `input-id` with the ID of your textarea)_

Comment: Thanks! It worked a charm. You helped me understand how to work with javascript in iframes in general as well, in just a couple of lines.
Could you post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include TinyMCE into a page, it registers the `tinymce` variable to the `window` of that page, so that you can access it and setup your editor.

When that page is inside an iframe, to access this `window` from the parent, you can do:

```
$('#iframe')[0].contentWindow;
// or `document.querySelector('#iframe).contentWindow` in plain JS
```

Once you know this, it's easy to access the TinyMCE editor's contents:

```
$("#iframe")[0].contentWindow.tinymce.editors["input-id"].getContent();
```